# Should there be a Discussion tag in Anime & Manga?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I just asked a very subjective question about Evangelion ([Is the Evangelion Remake a remake or a sequel?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/7722/is-the-evangelion-remake-a-remake-or-a-sequel)) to with I really want only opinions and not really a concrete answer. So I would have liked to add a discussion tag to indicate this. Why doesn't Anime & Manga manga have one? I know from personal expience that a lot of questions about anime are more oppinions than factual question with factual answers.

And maybe it is just me, but a cold Q&A like SO would be kinda dull. There are times when you simply want and oppinion and there are times when you want an answer. Especially for something like Anime and Manga. Taking into considerations the reaction to this question ([Should we explicitly allow discussions?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145/should-we-explicitly-allow-discussions)) I think it would be well worth it.

Comment: Why did this question get three downvotes?

Comment: @MiharuDante Meta works kinda differently from normal Q&A, this is simply to indicate that the feature-request was shot down.

Answer (score 4):

Well, there are different channels for you to take then. This isn't a forum, and as such, isn't fit well for a discussion.

If you have enough rep (Which you do) you can always join us in **[chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697)** for discussions and whatnot.

If you don't want to use chat, then sadly Anime & Manga Stack Exchange isn't the place to ask your subjective questions. :(

Comment: I get it that this is more of a Q&A and hell if I would allow something like this in SO, but with my own question for example I would love to have mark of the responses to refrence and point to. (Chats do not have this.) And is it really that bad for Anime & Manga to become more of a forum than a Q&A?

Comment: @idra: First off, chat *does* have bookmarked conversation and stars. You can use the in your advantage. Second, it's not about being bad or good. This is the type of site it is.